# Find logs of POD in AKS using Log Analytics Query

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

There is a AKS running that is connected to Log Analytics in Azure.
I'm trying to view logs of named PODs using the following query snippet:

```
let KubePodLogs = (clustername:string, podnameprefix:string) {
    let ContainerIdList = KubePodInventory
    | where ClusterName =~ clustername
    | where Name startswith strcat(podnameprefix, "-")
    | where strlen(ContainerID)>0
    | distinct ContainerID;
    ContainerLog
    | where ContainerID in (ContainerIdList)
    | join (KubePodInventory | project ContainerID, Name, PodLabel, Namespace, Computer) on ContainerID
    | project TimeGenerated, Node=Computer, Namespace, PodName=Name1, PodLabel, ContainerID, LogEntry
};
KubePodLogs('aks-my-cluster', 'my-service') | order by TimeGenerated desc
```

The above query does return rows of the matching PODs but not all that are actually available.

Trying to get results of the partial queries by inspecting POD details:

```
KubePodInventory
    | where ClusterName =~ 'aks-my-cluster'
    | where Name startswith 'my-service-'
    | where strlen(ContainerID)>0
    | distinct ContainerID;
```

gives me a container-id. Now feeding this container-id into another query shows more
results then the combined query from above. Why ?

```
ContainerLog 
| where ContainerID == "aec001...fc31"
| order by TimeGenerated desc 
| project TimeGenerated, ContainerID, LogEntry
```

One thing I noticed is that the later simple query result contain log results that have a `LogEntry` field parsed from JSON formatted output of the POD. In the results I can expand `LogEntry`to more fields corresponding to the original JSON data of that POD log output.

I.e. it seems like the combined query ( with a join ) skips those JSON `LogEntry` `ContainerLog` entries, but why ?

As far as I can see the combined query doesn't filter in any way on the `LogEntry` field.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed that the combined query results in rows that show the same LogEntry data for all rows. Maybe the "join" with the following "project" is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

A changed query seems to produce the results I would expect:

I exchanged the `join` with a `lookup` and used more columns to distinct the `KubePodInventory` results.

```
let KubePodLogs = (clustername:string, podnameprefix:string) {
    let ContainerIdList = KubePodInventory
    | where ClusterName =~ clustername
    | where Name startswith strcat(podnameprefix, "-")
    | where strlen(ContainerID)>0
    | distinct ContainerID, PodLabel, Namespace, PodIp, Name;
    ContainerLog
    | where ContainerID in (ContainerIdList)
    | lookup kind=leftouter (ContainerIdList) on ContainerID
    | project-away Image, ImageTag, Repository, Name, TimeOfCommand
    | project-rename PodName=Name1
};
KubePodLogs('aks-my-cluster', 'my-service') | order by TimeGenerated desc
```